# Custom class libraries in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to write a class library in Typescript and deploy it to NPM with a definitions file.

The classes in the library are essentially models that are shared across our various RESTful services. Some of them have a few utility functions.

In my current process, I've created a single module where all of the classes can be accessed from (index.js). And then I manually maintain a .d.ts that has all of the class and interface definitions. Any time I make a change to the actual implementation, I must remember to also update the definition file.

When I deploy to our private NPM server, I only deploy the the transpiled .js files and the definitions file. Services that install my npm package just need to add a single `/// <reference path="..." />` to their references file.

This works; it's just cumbersome and error-prone. Is there a decent/easy way for me to generate a single definitions file automatically from all of the classes I have? If not, is there something different I can/should do to share common Typescript modules across projects?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add --declaration to your compiler options and it will create the corresponding d.ts file/s for you. No need to do that manually.

Comment: Is there a way to combine all definitions into a single file? I've exposed all of the classes through a single module so I would only need to do use one `import classes = require('classes');` in any file.

Comment: Yes, add **--out lib.js** to your compiler options. This will create one js file lib.js and one declarations file lib.d.ts